# How to declare const in class and get the fields name against mailchimp list

Tags: php, curl, mailchimp

I am trying to get the specific fields name against mailchimp list id but i am unable to find the right solution.I am new to mailchimp and here i want to get the specific fields name like emailaddress firstname and lastname:

My controller code looks like:

```
   public function getFields()
{
    const REQUEST_URL = 'https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0';
    $ch = curl_init(REQUEST_URL.$list.'/members/?fields=members.email_address','members.first_name','members.last_name');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . 'xxxxxxyyyyyyzzzzz-us17');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $error = curl_error ( $ch );
    curl_close($ch);

}
```

when i hit my url in postman it says:

```
                     Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'const' (T_CONST)
```

i dont know how to define this cons outside of function anyone can guide me to the proper code from this:
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to declare constants in your function/method. The proper place to create a constant is a class.

```
const REQUEST_URL = 'https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0';

public function getFields()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: it says Use of undefined constant REQUEST_URL - assumed 'REQUEST_URL' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Comment: If it in class method, you should call e.g. `self::REQUEST_URL`, please read the official doc – http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

Comment: ok this issue is fixed now i when i hit url in postman it display nothing where i am doing wrong?

Comment: here the variable $list which is along self::REQUEST_URL , will it be the list id ($list)?